# Google Cloud functions gen 2 how to specify region and appcheck in source code

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using the first gen cloud functions it is easy to specify a region like this:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const someFunction = functions
  .runWith({
    enforceAppCheck: true,
  })
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https
  .onRequest((req, res) => {
```

But using the second gen there doesn't seem to be an option to do this, there is documentation that specificies that you can deploy them to a region, but this is not desirable.

The current code for the second gen is:

```js
import {onCall, HttpsError} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const someFunction = onCall(async (request) => {
```

Any tips or insights are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions),

The following works:

```js
export const someFunction = onCall(
  {
    enforceAppCheck: true,
    region: "europe-west1",
  },
```